# The variance of a random variable related to a geometric random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ be a fixed number.

We perform a sequence of Bernoulli trials until we get the first success. Each trial is performed with some probability. It is not important what are the particular probabilities and how they are defined, but we know that each of them is at least $\alpha$.

Let $X$ be the random variable of the number of trials in the above sequence.

My question is how one could upper bound Var($X$) in terms of $\alpha$?

Comment: Let me check my understanding: You are given $\alpha$.  You do not know $p_j$, the probability of success in the $j$th trial.  You want an upperbound $B \ge Var(X)$ that works for any such $\{p_1, p_2, ...\}$ as long as $\forall j: p_j \ge \alpha$.  Am I right?

Comment: @antkam, exactly, you are right. (In fact, I know $p_i$'s, but I pretend that I don't know them, as they may be arbitrary satisfying the inequalities $p_i \geq \alpha$)

Comment: Intuitively, I would guess $Var(X)$ is maximized when $\forall j: p_j = \alpha$.  In this case $X$ is just a geometric r.v. with $Var(X) = (1 - \alpha) / \alpha^2$ according to wikipedia.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was also thinking about. I just wanted to know what would be formal arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove that...  One possibility: given arbitrary $\vec{p}$, prove that if we lower $p_1$ to $\alpha$ then $Var(X)$ increases.  Then, now that $p_1 = \alpha$, prove that if we lower $p_2$ to $\alpha$ then $Var(X)$ increases.  Since the change is very "controlled" at each step, this has a chance to be tractable, but I havent thought this through.

Comment: After some more thought, the proof approach in my previous comment won't work.  There are vectors $\vec{p}$ s.t. if you lower each $p_j$ to $\alpha$ one by one, starting from $p_1$, then $Var(X)$ actually decreases at first before increasing.  I still think that all $p_j = \alpha$ (i.e. geometric r.v.) is the right solution, but that proof approach just won't work (coz it's false).

Comment: I heard that the coupling method may be useful for the problem. However, I know nothing about it and have to learn it first.